# How can I connect the VGA 15 Pin?

Tags: vga

I have 9 wire of different color like **White, Grey, Black, Violet, Blue, Green, Red, orange and Yellow**. I dont know how to connect.

Answer (score 1):

Your questions not the clearest TBH, maybe look at making it clearer by adding more information. I'm not quite sure exactly what you're trying to do. If its simply connecting a VGA connector then you will find a VGA wiring diagram [here](http://image.pinout.net/pinout_vga_files/connector_pinout.php?image=k74_recre_arcade_vga_pinout_02.gif&pinout=%20K%2074%20Arcade%20VGA%20pinout)

Picture included for completeness:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would not rely on the colour of the wires. Each manufacturer may have used a different colour code. However, if you know what each wire "does", the German Wikipedia article has a [VGA pinout](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/VGA-Anschluss#Steckverbindung). Translating from that article:

1. Red
2. Green
3. Blue
4. ID2
5. Ground for DDC
6. Ground for red
7. Ground for green
8. Ground for blue
9. n/c
10. Ground for sync
11. ID0
12. ID1 or DDC data
13. Horizontal sync
14. Vertical sync
15. DDC clock

The numbers relate to this picture from Wikimedia Commons, but should also be printed on your connector:

[image: VGA connector pinout from Wikimedia Commons]